# Creating a UITableView with Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase

I'm trying to create a UITableView of the data shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqzuT.png). What I want to have is a list of all the "Walks" name's and ignore the other data for now. So for example the list would be Apple Run, Walk, etc.

The code I have so far is this:

```
 self.walksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 NSString *userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"User_ID"];

 Firebase* listRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myFirebase.firebaseio.com/users/%@/walks/", userID]];

 [listRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    // 
    [self.walksArray addObject:snapshot.value];
    NSLog(@"Snapshot: %@", snapshot.value);

    // Reload the table view so the new walk will show up.
    [self.walksListTableView reloadData];
 }];
```

What this gives me is

```
{
"Apple Run" =     (
            {
        latitude = "37.335072";
        longitude = "-122.032604";
        time = "00:19:40";
    },
            {
        latitude = "37.335072";
        longitude = "-122.032604";
        time = "00:19:43";
    },
            {
        latitude = "37.335072";
        longitude = "-122.032604";
        time = "00:19:47";
    },
            {
        latitude = "37.335072";
        longitude = "-122.032604";
        time = "00:19:49";
    }
);
Walk =     (
            {
        latitude = "37.334922";
        longitude = "-122.033042";
        time = "00:40:50";
    },
...
```

What I can't figure out is how to 'strip' the rest of the data and just show the name of the walk.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `snapshot.name`? [example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html#section-getting-data)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in replying. No, that would just return "walks". I want to go one level deeper and get the next part of the URL. So if I use "https://myFirebase.firebaseio.com/users/%@/walks/" I would get the names of the walks for that user.